# C++ error C2664 and error C2679

Tags: c++

So my code is below.  i tried looking this stuff up but it usually doesnt help with my situation.  any help is a blessing.

#### Compiler Errors:

```
error C2679: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
    counter[typeOfToken]+=1;

error C2664: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::count' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'const tokentype &'
    if (counter.count(typeOfToken))
```

#### Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

enum tokentype{ lANGLE=1, rANGLE=2,iD=3, eQ=4, sLASH=5, qSTRING=6, oTHER=7, eND=8, tEXT=9};
tokentype getToken(istream *in, string& lexeme);

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    istream *br;
    ifstream infile;
    // check args and open the file
    if( argc == 1 )
        br = &cin;
    else if( argc != 2 ) {
        cout<<"THERE IS A FATAL ERROR"<<endl;
        return 1; // print an error msg
    } else {
        infile.open(argv[1]);
        if( infile.is_open() )
            br = &infile;
        else {
            cout << argv[1] << " can't be opened" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    map <tokentype, int> counter;
    string tokens="";
    int typeOfToken;

    while(true){
        typeOfToken=getToken(br,tokens);
        if (counter.count(typeOfToken))
            counter[typeOfToken]+=1;
        else
            counter[typeOfToken]=1;

        if(typeOfToken==eND)
            break;
    }

    cout<<"total token count: "<<endl;
    if (counter[lANGLE]!=0)
        cout<<"LANGLE: "<<counter[lANGLE]<<endl;
    if (counter[rANGLE]!=0)
        cout<<"RANGLE: "<<counter[rANGLE]<<endl;
    if (counter[tEXT]!=0)
        cout<<"TEXT: "<<counter[tEXT]<<endl;
    if (counter[iD]!=0)
        cout<<"ID: "<<counter[iD]<<endl;
    if (counter[eQ]!=0)
        cout<<"EQ: "<<counter[eQ]<<endl;
    if (counter[sLASH]!=0)
        cout<<"SLASH: "<<counter[sLASH]<<endl;
    if (counter[qSTRING]!=0)
        cout<<"QSTRING: "<<counter[qSTRING]<<endl;
    if (counter[oTHER]!=0)
        cout<<"OTHER: "<<counter[oTHER]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should be `tokentype typeOfToken;` instead of `int`?

Comment: thank you soooo much.  it now compiles properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a type mismatch on the `typeOfToken` variable.

It comes from `getToken`, which returns type `enum tokentype`.  It gets used as an index into a `std::map` keyed on `enum tokentype`.  Both these operations work great if you declare `tokentype typeOfToken;`

However, you didn't.  You made it an `int`.  Enumeration values implicitly convert to integral types, but the reverse conversion is explicit (needs a cast) and gives the error you saw if you forget that.

Of course, fixing the variable type to match its usage is ideal, and in this case you can.  But if its usage was mixed (perhaps it was used in arithmetic somewhere), then you would need a cast.